# Find the largest number in array

Tags: c

I try to find largest number using array and pointer, but program gives errors on "finding step". Can you tell me where is my mistake?

```
void find_two_largest(int a[], int n, int *largest)
   {
          int i; 
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("enter %d. value: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
       int max=a[0];

       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           if(a[i]>max)    max=a[i];


         largest=&max;

       printf("%d",*largest);
           }

 int main()
   {
int n,i,a[100],*lar=NULL;

printf("how many elements you want to store?\t");
scanf("%d",&n);

find_two_largest(a, n, lar);

return 0;
       }
```

Comment: Debugger................

Comment: 'errors on "finding step" what errors?  Where is 'finding step'?

Comment: 'lar' is uninitialized.

Comment: for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(a[i]>max)    max=a[i];

Comment: 'int n,i,a[100],*lar,*slar;'   The 'lar' pointer has automatic storage.  It is not initialized, so '*largest=max;' is UB.

Comment: What does `max=a[0];` do?  It attempts to read `a[0]` which may not have any valid value in it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove * from lar definition.
like this it should be :

```
int n,i,a[100], lar,*slar;
```

and then add an & to function call :

```
find_two_largest(a, n, &lar);
```

and after that put max = a[0] after a[0] value set.

Comment: I tried it but it gives this error: cannot conver 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '3' to 'void find_two_largest(int*,int,int*)'

Comment: just edited. check this. works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The main program is not initializing `*lar`, the `find_two_largest` function is initializing `max` before set user values, so max could be any value in memory.

```
void find_two_largest(int a[], int n, int *largest)
{
    int i,max;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("enter %d. value: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    //initialize max after entering values
    max=a[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(a[i]>max)    max=a[i];


    *largest=max;

    printf("%d",*largest);

}


int main()
{
    int n,i,a[100],*lar,*slar;

    //initialize;     
    *lar=INT_MIN;

    printf("how many elements you want to store?\t");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    find_two_largest(a, n, lar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I try to do it with pass by address